# Jackson CsvMapper nested object field

Tags: java, csv, jackson

I want to serialize/deserialize Pojos to csv format with jackson CsvMapper. My pojos:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    String name;

    @JsonUnwrapped(prefix = "||")
    Role role;

    String email;
}

public class Role implements Serializable {

    Long id;

    String name;
}
```

What I'm getting now:

```
name|email|||id|||name 
New User|newuser@gmail.com|1|User 
New User2|newuser2@gmail.com|1|User 
New User3|newuser3@gmail.com|1|User
```

I'm expecting to get content with separators like:

```
New User|newuser@gmail.com|||1|User
```

(only nested object separated with additional separators, not its field and also separators must be applied to data, not only to header)
Also I need to move nested object inside row. For example expected result:

```
New User|||1|User|||newuser@gmail.com
```

My current code for schema and serialization:

```
 CsvSchema userSchema = csvMapper
            .schemaFor(User.class)
            .sortedBy("name", "role.name", "role.id", "email")
            .withoutQuoteChar()
            .withColumnReordering(true)
            .withColumnSeparator('|')
            .withHeader();

        csvMapper.writer(userSchema).writeValueAsString(users);
```